# Can't publish on Facebook using Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using `com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment` to manage login/logout:

```
Fragment userSettingsFragment = new UserSettingsFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, userSettingsFragment, "userSettingsFragment");
```

Then in another `Fragment` I want to publish a message on Facebook. I check the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) and wrote `MyFragment` shown below.

The connection with `com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment` seems to works (I can login/logout), but when I want to publish in `MyFragment`, it seems that `session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);` does not change the `Session`, because `onSessionStateChange` is never called.

It calls some `Facebook` UI to ask for permission, and then nothing happens.

Can I just use `com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment` for login/logout, i.e. does it manage all the Facebook SDK objects? I'm wondering because `Session.getActiveSession();` in `MyFragment` always returns a `Session`, even when I'm logged out.

Anybody can help?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private Button mBtnShare;

    private UiLifecycleHelper mUiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publish();
            }
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = 
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mBtnShare = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
        mBtnShare.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               publish();
            }

        );
    }   


    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mUiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), mCallback);
        mUiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();
        mUiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mUiHelper.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        mUiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        mUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }   

    private void publish() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "JSON error "+ e.getMessage(), MyApplication.LOG_LEVEL);
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                .getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                .getApplicationContext(), 
                                postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having same problem with the new SDK then I just added the publishPermissions  at the loginButton itself. Now I have both the read and publish permissions in my app at the same time. You can check the sample app made by me at this link : https://code.google.com/p/list-high-light/downloads/list

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using the loginButton, I'm using the default `UserSettingsFragment` provided by `Facebook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the permissions for every request like in the example code, I set it directly in the `com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment`:

```
UserSettingsFragment userSettingsFragment = new UserSettingsFragment();                 
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if(session==null || session.isClosed()){
    userSettingsFragment.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, userSettingsFragment, "userSettingsFragment");
```

Comment: This won't really work for new users (users who have never used your app before). The reason is because you can't request both read and publish permissions at the same time. The correct method is to use UserSettingsFragment to only manage your "read" permissions, and in your "MyFragment", whenever you need to publish, check if you have publish permissions, and if you don't, call session.newPermissionsRequest (but remember to also override the onActivityResult method in that fragment as well).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Login only works for single activity of your application. You need mention the activity name and package name while your creating facebook appid. So Finally Facebook authentication and posting only works for specified activity.

Comment: I've only got one `Activity` in my app. The authentication and publish are done in `Fragments`, as shown in my code.

Comment: Try the Facebook authentication and publish in Activity instead of Fragment.

Comment: I'd like to keep my app organized into `Fragments`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is identical to the tutorial of feed on Facebook and I can't find the difference. Maybe the `UiLifecycleHelper` doesn't invoke the `call` method of `StatusCallback` after you see the Facebook UI popup permissions.

Just to verify, add `session.addCallback(mCallback);` in:

```
// Check for publish permissions    
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    // -- here ---
    session.addCallback(mCallback);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    return;
}
```

Then, debug and check that `onSessionStateChange` is called. If it was called, don't leave this line, but check in your logcat or debug the problem inside the `UiLifecycleHelper` why it didn't invoke the `call()` method of `StatusCallback`. If it wasn't called, then probably you have permissions or login issue.

**Beside these checks**, you can use this [**android-simple-facebook**](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

You can easily **login** / **logut**, **publish feeds** / **photos** and more without any painful coding you made. There is also a sample app that has in addition to simple examples, the example with **fragment**.

#### Example of login:

```
mSimpleFacebook.login(onLoginListener);
```

#### Example of publish feed:

```
Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
           .setMessage("Clone it out...")
           .setName("Simple Facebook for Android")
           .setCaption("Code less, do the same.")
           .setDescription("The Simple Facebook library project makes the life much easier by coding less code for being able to login, publish feeds and open graph stories, invite friends and more.")
           .setPicture("https://raw.github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/master/Refs/android_facebook_sdk_logo.png")
           .setLink("https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook")
           .build();

// publish the feed
mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);
```

**And,** you **don't** need to care for right sequence of asking **READ and PUBLISH permissions**. You can set all permissions you intend to use in your app and the library will trigger the Facebook permission dialogs on connect one after another, or if you decline the PUBLISH permission in the dialog, it will trigger again the dialog on publish action